# Get monitors outputting from second graphics card (Linux)

Tags: linux, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

**OS**
Kali 1.0.6
Linux Kernel 3.12.6

**Relevant Hardware**
HD7950 x 3 (not in crossfire)
BenQ G2420HD 1920x1080 monitors x 4
Kogan 2560x1440 monitors x 2

**Situation**
Recently installed Kali along with AMD drivers. Currently Kali detects the 4 BenQ monitors being outputted via graphics card 1, but not the two additional monitors outputted via graphics card 2.

Kali detects all 3 graphics cards as confirmed with the *lspci* command.

The Catalyst Control Center shows the 4 working monitors along with two "unknown" disabled monitors. The only options to enable these monitors is as "Multi-Display > Single display desktop (Multi-Desktop)", not as the required "Multi-display desktop with displays 1,2,3,4".

aticonfig --query-monitor shows an error given that RandR 1.2 is enabled, and only shows the 4 BenQ monitors active, with others disconnected. I am happy to paste the full output if necessary.

**What I wish to achieve**
Ideally I want to have all 6 monitors working as a multi screen desktop display, as I did have successfully in Windows. If I can have GPU 2 / 3 in crossfire while having GPU 1 without crossfire that would be great also, but the monitors are my main priority.

Any help is greatly appreciated, will happily provide any further information as required.

Edit: Bounty added for anyone who can get all 6 monitors working with crossfire enabled on graphics card 2/3 which will be supporting to two Kogan monitors. Graphics card 1 working on the 4 outputs for the 4 BenQ monitors.

Comment: Maybe you should move this question to http://unix.stackexchange.com to get more answers/comments.

Answer (score 0):

Edit /etc/ati/amdpcsdb
In the section labeled [AMDPCSROOT/SYSTEM/DDX]
add this:

```
EnableRandR12=Sfalse
```

Also, in /etc/X11/xorg.conf in the "Device" section add:

```
Option "EnableRandR12" "false"
```

Hope that helps.